# Spring security returns 401 when database is stopped

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have configured spring basic authentication with custom authentication manager. My authentication manager will access database for user information. When Database is stopped and application trying to authenticate user, my application returns 401 (unauthorized). But my expected behavior is to return 500 (Internal server error) in this case. Below is how I have configured spring security.

```html
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.security" />

 <sec:http use-expressions="true">

  <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('Admin','Data Operator','Data Collector')" />
  <sec:http-basic />
  
 </sec:http>

 <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <sec:authentication-provider
   user-service-ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
   <sec:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
  </sec:authentication-provider>
 </sec:authentication-manager>

 <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
  class="com.test.security.MyUserDetailsService" />


 <bean id="encoder"
   class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
 </bean>
```

Below is the implementation of authenticate provider

```
package com.test.security;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.business.objects.Adminrole;
import com.test.business.objects.Adminuser;
import com.test.business.repository.AdminroleRepository;
import com.test.repository.AdminuserRepository;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private AdminuserRepository adminuserRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AdminroleRepository adminroleRepository;






    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{



        //find admin user by user name
        List<Adminuser> adminUsers = adminuserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        Adminuser adminUser = adminUsers.get(0);

        //find admin roles by user
        List<Adminrole> adminRoles = adminroleRepository.getAdminRolesByUserId(adminUser.getUserid());

        //create user details object
        MyUserDetails userdetails = new MyUserDetails(adminUser, adminRoles);
        return userdetails;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have anyone used AuthenticationFailureHandler with spring basic authentication mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```html
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.security" />

 <sec:http use-expressions="true">

  <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('Admin','Data Operator','Data Collector')" />
  <sec:http-basic  entry-point-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
  
 </sec:http>

 <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <sec:authentication-provider
   user-service-ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
   <sec:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
  </sec:authentication-provider>
 </sec:authentication-manager>

 <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
  class="com.test.security.MyUserDetailsService" />

 <bean id="encoder"
   class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
 </bean>
<bean id="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
  class="com.test.MyAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
```

```
package com.test.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;

@Component
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint  extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint{
     @Override
        public void commence
          (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
          throws IOException, ServletException {

            if (authEx.getCause() instanceof TransactionException){
                 response.addHeader("Internal Server Error", "Basic realm='" + getRealmName() + "'");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }else{
                response.addHeader("Authenticate-Faliure", "Basic realm='" + getRealmName() + "'");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            setRealmName("test");
            super.afterPropertiesSet();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UsernameNotFoundException.html) javadoc. It shows that UsernameNotFoundException is an AuthenticationException. My guess is that you are catching an exception when accessing the database and converting it to UsernameNotFoundException. Take a look at your database code, that's probably where the issue lies.

Comment: No, I'm using spring JPA repositories to access the  database, No explicitly handle exceptions.

Comment: Post the code for: adminuserRepository.findByUsername

Comment: Oh, and I am assuming it works with the database started!

Comment: package com.test.repository;

@Repository
public interface AdminuserRepository 
      extends JpaRepository<Adminuser, Integer> {
 
     @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public List<Adminuser> findByUsername(String username);

}

Comment: When you add code, add it to the question so that you can format it and make it readable. You have posted an interface - post the code that implements it.

Comment: No need to have implementation for JPA repository, It's how spring access the database (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this is the correct behavior for a resilient service.  Why should the whole server break if just the authentication is broken?  There may be public available resources of the server which should be available anyway even without a user database reachable. Even when a user logged in and got a token for example, why shouldn't he access protected resources as long as the token is valid? The Spring Security team did a great job here implementing it just in the way they did. You should not change the behavior.

Comment: Simple user scenario is like this, You try to access the application when database server is down. If server returns 401 user thinks credentials must be wrong. I think User should notify he can't access the application due to application error.

Comment: Feel free to create messages on a error page checking health of the database if really needed. On the other hand it is also a security feature not to tell everyone about the reason (unknown user, wrong password, database down, …)